# Method calling of Custom view in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, custom-view

I want to know the answer of these following questions. These questions are based on Custom view.

**Q1.** I have read `onAttachedToWindow` documentation from android docs. What is meaning of this line

> however it may be called any time before the first onDraw -- **including before or after onMeasure(int, int)**.

According to me, Meaning of bold text line is : onAttachedToWindow  can be call after or before the onMeasure method. If I am not wrong then, in which case onAttachedToWindow will call after onMeasure ?

**Q2.** What is use-case of `onAttachedToWindow`?

**Q3.** Why `onMeasure` called twice for below code?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.sessiondemo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.mycustomview.customview
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:textColor="#ffffff"
    custom:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout
```

In this, I am using Linear layout. Why customview called twice?

**Q4.** why `onMeasure` also called after `onSizeChanged` method?

**Q5.** Why height, width calculated by `onSizeChanged()`  is not same with height, width calculated by `onMeasure`?

Comment: Add customview.java class then anybody can explain